# Embedded GWT Widget not responding to Mouse Events

Tags: events, gwt, widget

I have a GWT widget that I want to embed in a non-GWT application. I am using [get-exporter](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter/)  to expose my API and I have the widget appearing in a simple HTML page (which includes my nocache.js) and drawing itself. What it does ***not*** do is respond to mouse clicks.

I attach the widget to a div like this (objects are exposed using get-exporter):

```
   controller = new GraphController(MakeGraphConfig.makeGraphConfig());
   var element = controller.getGraphPanelElement() ;
   document.getElementById('graphPanelId').appendChild(element);
```

The element 'graph' is a simple **div** and a direct child of the **body** element.

```
<div width="500" height="500" id="graphPaneId" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 11px; "></div>
```

The widget draws and does not respond to mouse events. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to pass the elementId into the controller:

Javascript:

controller = new GraphController("graphPanelId",MakeGraphConfig.makeGraphConfig());

and use :

Java:

RootPanel.get(elementId).add(graphPanel)